# Test a step that yields the same instance multiple times

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a step that splits up Pubsub messages on newline in Dataflow. We have a test that passes for the code, but it seems to fail in production. Looks like we get the same Pubsub message in multiple places in the pipeline at once (to the best of my knowledge at least).

Should we have written the first test in another way? Or is this just a hard lesson learned about what not to do in Apache Beam?

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import PubsubMessage
from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline
from apache_beam.testing.util import assert_that, equal_to
import unittest

class SplitUpBatches(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, msg):
        bodies = msg.data.split('\n')
        for body in bodies:
            msg.data = body.strip()
            yield msg

class TestSplitting(unittest.TestCase):
    body = """
    first
    second
    third
    """.strip()

    def test_incorrectly_passing(self):
        """Incorrectly passing"""
        msg = PubsubMessage(self.body, {})
        with TestPipeline() as p:
            assert_that(
                p
                | beam.Create([msg])
                | "split up batches" >> beam.ParDo(SplitUpBatches())
                | "map to data" >> beam.Map(lambda m: m.data),
                equal_to(['first', 'second', 'third']))

    def test_correctly_failing(self):
        """Failing, but not using a TestPipeline"""
        msg = PubsubMessage(self.body, {})
        messages = list(SplitUpBatches().process(msg))
        bodies = [m.data for m in messages]
        self.assertEqual(bodies, ['first', 'second', 'third'])
        # => AssertionError: ['third', 'third', 'third'] != ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Yes, this is an example of what *not to do in Beam*: Reutilize (mutate) your element objects.

In fact, Beam discourages mutating inputs and outputs of your transforms, because Beam passes/buffers those objects in various ways that can be affected if you mutate them.

The recommendation here is to create a new `PubsubMessage` instance for each output.

---

#### Detailed explanation

This happens due to the ways in which Beam serializes and passes data around.

You may know that Beam executes several steps together in single workers - what we call stages. Your pipeline does something like this:

```
read_data -> split_up_batches -> serialize all data -> perform assert
```

This intermediate `serialize data` step is an implementation detail. The reason is that for the Beam `assert_that` we gather all of the data of a single PCollection into a single machine, and perform the assert (thus we need to serialize all elements and send them over to a single machine). We do this with a *GroupByKey* operation.

When the `DirectRunner` receives the first `yield` of a `PubsubMessage('first')`, it serializes it and *transfers it to a GroupByKey* immediately - so you get the `'first', 'second', 'third'` result - because serialization happens immediately.

When the `DataflowRunner` receives the first `yield` of a `PubsubMessage('first')`, it **buffers it**, and sends over a batch of elements. You get the `'third', 'third', 'third'` result, because serialization happens after a buffer is transmitted over - and your original `PubsubMessage` instance has been overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Instantiating more messages in that particular step seems to have solved that error. What I still don't get is how we can have errors due to serialized messages, both in one of the first steps (after deserialization) and in one of the last steps (when trying to re-serialize). If we're yielding the same message multiple times or have branching it makes sense, but those steps are in a direct hierarchy with no parallel step changing the messages. Either way, implementing the same fix everywhere seems to solve that.